# Writing hex representation to file

Tags: c

In my program, I am trying to read data from binary file, and then write it's hex representation to txt file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int counter = 0;
int read;
int i = 0;
long size;
FILE *file1 = NULL; 
FILE *file2 = NULL; 
fpos_t length;
char newLine = '\n';

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Use: %s file1 file2", argv[0]);
    exit (-1);
    }

    unsigned char hex[513];
    unsigned char buffer[257];
    file1 = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    fseek(file1, 0, SEEK_END);
    fgetpos(file1, &length);
    size = length.__pos;
    fseek(file1, 0, SEEK_SET); 
    if (file1) {
            file2 = fopen(argv[2], "w");
            if (!file2) {
                    printf("Cannot open file: %s\n", argv[2]);
                    exit(-1);
            }
            while (counter < size) {
                    read = fread(buffer, 1, 256, file1);
                    counter += read;
                    i = 0;
                    while (i < read) {
                            sprintf(hex, "%02x",  buffer[i++]);
                    }
                    fwrite(hex, 1, 512, file2);
                    fwrite(&newLine, 1, 1, file2);
                    }
    } else
           printf("Cannot open file %s\n", argv[1]);
    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
}
```

Unfortunately data don't write to txt file properly. Please help me find my mistake. What is wrong in this code?

Comment: You *really* need to learn how to indent your code. Indentation will help you a lot in the future.

Comment: Printing values in hex has been asked (and answered) many times over on SO. Please use the site search.

Comment: fwrite(hex, 1, 512, file2) -> fwrite(hex, 1, read*2, file2);

Comment: sprintf(hex, "%02x",  buffer[i++]) -> sprintf(hex + 2 * i, "%02x",  buffer[i++]);

Comment: fclose(file1) -> on a potentially failed to open file handle

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=C%2B%2B+print+hex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the issue is that the `sprintf` call will keep overwriting whatever is in `hex`.  It does not append to it.  So the result is that it writes the full size of that buffer to the file, but it will only have the very last hex value in it (in the first 2 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

Here's your (main) problem:

```
while (i < read) {
  sprintf(hex, "%02x",  buffer[i++]);                     
}
```

You're not *appending* the hex representation of `buffer[i++]` to `hex`, you're *overwriting* what's in `hex`.

Here's one (slightly hackish and ugly) way around the problem:

```
usigned char *hp = hex;
...
while (i < read) {
  sprintf(hp, "%02x", buffer[i++]);
  hp+=2;      
}
```

`hp` initially points to the beginning of `hex`; each time through the loop, you advance it two places, so that each `sprintf` *does* append to `hex`.

Note that `sizeof(hex)` will *always* evaluate to 513 regardless of how many values you actually store in it.  Better to write `2*read` if you're trying to indicate how many characters have been written to each line.